# How to Display retieve into my Textbox in aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this code and i would like to ask ways how to display the result of my query into my textbox named "Textbox1"

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" inherits="MainPage, App_Web_rlctbjj5" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TDBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

string query = "SELECT news, news_date FROM [IBSI].[dbo].[ibsi.news]";

if (query != null)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {

      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (rdr.HasRows)
      {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

          Response.Write("<p>");
          Response.Write("<strong>" + rdr["news"].ToString() + "</strong><br />");
          Response.Write(rdr["news_date"].ToString() + "</p>");

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
else 
{
  Response.Write("<p>No customer selected</p>"); 
}
Response.End();
}
</script>   

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">





<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>iBSI SLA Manager</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
<meta name="keywords" content="iBSI SLA Manager" />
<meta name="description" content="SLA Manager" />
<meta name="author" content="iBSI" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2010-2011 by Wenchester M. Visitacion" />
<meta name="company" content="iBSI SLA Manager" />
<%--  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../styles/images/favicon.ico" />--%>
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="Styles/images/IBSI_LOGO.png" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/CoreStyle.css?version=1.0.1" type="text/css"
    media="all" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/widget/Toaster/Toaster.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojo/resources/dojo.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/resources/Grid.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/resources/claroGrid.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/form/resources/CheckedMultiSelect.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/form/resources/FileInput.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claroEnhancedGrid.css"
    type="text/css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/style.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/carosel.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
$(".newsticker-jcarousellite").jCarouselLite({
    vertical: true,
    hoverPause:true,
    visible: 3,
    auto:500,
    speed:3000
});
});
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.CheckboxTree");
    dojo.require("dojo.CheckboxForestStoreModel");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/CoreScript.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Dashboard.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Node.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Menu.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Role.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/RoleMembers.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/AccessRights.min.js?version=1.0.1">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/User.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Company.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Customer.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/TransactionType.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Transaction.min.js?version=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/WorkFlowIn.min.js?version=1.0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/WorkFlowOut.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DocumentControl.min.js?version=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Periodic.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/PeriodicInstruction.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/CustomerTransaction.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/CustomerConcern.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/TransactionInquiry.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/CustomerConcernInquiry.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/PeriodicInstructionInquiry.min.js?version=1.0.2"></script>
</head>
<body class="claro" style="background-color: #000000;">
<div dojotype="dojox.widget.Toaster" id="ToasterMessage" positiondirection="br-left"
    duration="500" messagetopic="ToasterMessage">
</div>
<div id="bc" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer">
    <div id="header" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" style="background-color: Transparent;
        height: 60px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="divLoginInfo" class="LoginInfo">
            <div>
                <span id="spanUsername">Hi User!</span> <span id="spanChangePassword" class="LinkDrill">
                    [Change Password]</span>&nbsp<span id="spanSignout" class="LinkDrill">[Signout]</span></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <div style="text-align: right;">
                    <span id="spanDate"></span>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: right;">
                    <span id="spanTime"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="Styles/images/sparkbanner.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: auto;" />
    </div>
    <div jsid="MainLeft" id="MainLeft" dojotype="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" splitter="true"
        duration="275" region="left" title="Menu" previewondblclick="true" maxwidth="230"
        style="background-color: Transparent; width: 210px;" easein="dojo.fx.easing.backOut"
        easeout="dojo.fx.easing.backInOut">
        <div dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="TabContainerMain" jsid="TabContainerMain"
            region="center" attachparent="true" tabposition="bottom" tabstrip="true" style="background-color: Transparent;
            border: 0px;">
            <div id="ContentPaneMain_Login" jsid="ContentPaneMain_Login" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
                style="background-color: Transparent;">
                <div style="padding-top: 50px; margin-left: 10px; background-color: Transparent;">
                    <div>
                        UserName:
                        <input jsid="TextBoxUserName" id="TextBoxUserName" dojotype="dijit.form.TextBox"
                            type="text" style="width: 90%;" selectonclick="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Password:
                        <input jsid="TextBoxPassword" id="TextBoxPassword" dojotype="dijit.form.TextBox"
                            type="password" style="width: 90%;" selectonclick="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button jsid="ButtonLogin" id="ButtonLogin" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" style="float: right;
                            padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">
                            Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <span id="spanMessage"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="MainRight" jsid="MainRight" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true"
        region="center" style="background-color: transparent; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
        <div dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="left" id="TCCenterPane" tabstrip="true"
            style="margin-top: -4px; border: 0px;">
            <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Home" selected="true" style="padding: 0px;
                background-color: #000000;">
                <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
                <div style="position:absolute;z-index:200; left:52.5%;top:9%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="168px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                            Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="news">
                <div class="newsticker-jcarousellite" style="position:absolute;z-index:200; left:52.5%;top:9%;">


                </div></div></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;z-index:200; left:52.5%;top:52%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="168px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                            Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                </form > 
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 90%; background: #000000 url(Styles/images/IBSI_LOGO1.png)  no-repeat center;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div jsid="DialogAlertMessage" id="DialogAlertMessage" dojotype="dijit.Dialog" title="Alert Box"
    style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <div style="width: 300px; min-height: 50px;">
        <span id="spanAlertMessage">Empty Alert Message</span>
        <br />
        <div style="float: right;">
            <button id="ButtonOKAlertMessage" jsid="ButtonOKAlertMessage" dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
                OK</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div jsid="DialogConfirmMessage" id="DialogConfirmMessage" dojotype="dijit.Dialog"
    title="Confirmation" title="Alert Box" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <div style="width: 300px">
        <span id="spanConfirmMessage">Empty Alert Message</span>
        <br />
        <div style="float: right">
            <button id="ButtonConfirmMessageYES" jsid="ButtonConfirmMessageYES" dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
                YES</button>
            <button id="ButtonConfirmMessageNO" jsid="ButtonConfirmMessageNO" dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
                NO</button>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<div jsid="DialogReportPreview" id="DialogReportPreview" dojotype="dijit.Dialog"
    aria-describedby="intro" title="Required" autofocus="true">
    <iframe id="iframeReportPreview" onload="StandbyPreview.hide()" frameborder="0" style="width: 900px;
        height: 500px;"></iframe>
</div>
<div jsid="StandbyPreview" id="StandbyPreview" dojotype="dojox.widget.Standby" color="#E4F4FC"
    target="TabContainerMain" zindex="9000" slidefrom="bottom" image="Styles/Images/Progress/loadingSmall.gif">
</div>
<div jsid="DialogChangePassword" id="DialogChangePassword" dojotype="dijit.Dialog"
    aria-describedby="intro" title="Change Password" autofocus="false">
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 520px;">
        <div style="width: 150px; padding: 15px 0px 10px  20px; height: 180px; float: left;">
            <div style="height: 165px; width: 140px; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
                To ensure system security, do not use familiar words for password initials, favorite
                expressions and names of love ones or popular persons. We suggest to change passwords
                regularly or once a month.</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100px; padding: 50px 0px 10px 10px; float: left; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                User Name:</div>
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                Old Password:</div>
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                New Password:</div>
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                Confirm Password:</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 200px; padding: 50px 0px 10px 10px; float: left;">
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <input jsid="TextBoxCurrentUserName" id="TextBoxCurrentUserName" dojotype="dijit.form.TextBox"
                    type="text" style="width: 100%;" selectonclick="true" readonly="true" /></div>
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <input jsid="TextBoxOldPassword" id="TextBoxOldPassword" dojotype="dijit.form.TextBox"
                    type="password" style="width: 100%;" selectonclick="true" /></div>
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <input jsid="TextBoxNewPassword" id="TextBoxNewPassword" dojotype="dijit.form.TextBox"
                    type="password" style="width: 100%;" selectonclick="true" /></div>
            <div style="height: 18px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <input jsid="TextBoxConfirmPassword" id="TextBoxConfirmPassword" dojotype="dijit.form.TextBox"
                    type="password" style="width: 100%;" selectonclick="true" /></div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; padding-right: 25px;">
            <button jsid="ButtonChangePassword" id="ButtonChangePassword" dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
                Proceed</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i use this to display the value of the retrieve data on screen.

```
Response.Write("<p>");
Response.Write("<strong>" + rdr["news"].ToString() + "</strong><br />");
Response.Write(rdr["news_date"].ToString() + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would write something like this :

```
TextBox1.Text = rdr["news"].ToString();
```

However it looks like your query is likely to return more than 1 row (and more than 1 column). The TextBox can only hold 1 value, so if you do that, you will only see the content of the last row.

In your case it is probably better to use a control that can display the value(s) of several rows, such as the [GridView](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331772452017&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx&ei=IjxhT_miCOGZiQeSqPW5Aw&usg=AFQjCNEIXOYwsrnkX7Ky507yJXFpLRebhQ), the [ListView](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331772506518&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx&ei=WDxhT5TnEZCQiQeQ__XSAg&usg=AFQjCNHlENSP9_p1O4zVpLPTRbmXcusysg), the [Repeater](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331772465545&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx&ei=MTxhT667A6ytiQfy-9HtBw&usg=AFQjCNFOiAqm_mUjSGGXMNCqKtkEkadWjw) or the [DataList](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331772475648&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx&ei=OzxhT_GsOYueiQeFvrzcBw&usg=AFQjCNFwdSncmukpLOSQV7SwdsBEBbTbBw).

Comment: i tried that and given me an error CS0103: The name 'Textbox1' does not exist in the current context. the textbox1 exist because i creatde it. . <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="168px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

It's using a dojo framework dude. So try how to use the controls here: http://dojotoolkit.org/.
for the dojo textbox, setting the value is dijit.byId('TextBox1').set('value', 'sampleValue');
I created that project from scratch. But I guess you were the one continued it. Goodluck. :)